# javascript clicking a html button does nothing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple bootstrap html layout setup, which contains 2 buttons `#add` and `#take`. When calling their functions before from the $(document).ready function, everything works, but since I will need to reuse the functions anyway I decided to put them outside.

Now when I click the button nothing happens. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[codepen](http://codepen.io/shooshte/pen/BjyrGb)

html:

```
<div clas="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <span>Session length:</span>
      <span class="session">25 min</span>
      <button id="add" class="btn btn-info">+</button>
      <button id="take" class="btn btn-info">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1 id="timer">25:00</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button id="start" class="btn btn-success">Start</button>
      <button id="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
function addMinute() {
  time + 60;
}

function removeMinute() {
  time - 60;
}

function updateSession(a) {
  $(".session").empty();
  $(".session").append(a + " min");
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
  var time = 1500;

  $("#add").click(function(time) {
    addMinute();
    updateSession(time);
  }) //end add.click
}); //end document.ready
```

Comment: how can you use jquery selectors without loading DOM.

Comment: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has to do with JavaScript scoping. Your `var time` is only visible inside that function, and not to the outer functions. You can fix this by making `time` a global variable or by passing it to the functions you want to use it in.

You can read more about JavaScript's lexical scoping [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

You also have other errors: `time + 60` should be `time += 60` and `time - 60` should be `time -= 60`.

Comment: updated codepen, still won't work =)

Comment: You have other errors: Change `time + 60` to `time += 60` and `time - 60` to `time -= 60`.

Comment: @saadq Time in the event handler is not what the OP thinks it is either. Time passed in will be the event object.

Comment: @ste2425 If you check is updated CodePen, he isn't passing in time anymore, he's using the correct `time` variable. Changing `time + 60` to `time += 60` seems to make it work for me.

Comment: @saadq aah my bad, didn't see the updated codepen, just his pasted code in the question.